# Custom Taxonomy archive.php template naming not working

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have Custom Taxonomy in my site, relating to "countries".

The actual slug is "country" and I thought to create a specific archive for that taxonomy I would just do this:

```
archive-{country}.php
```

However...for some reason it doesn't show or work?

I have a child theme but I also experimented with the main theme.

If I edit the archive.php then that works so I know the hierarchical structure works.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Please review the template hierarchy: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/ Taxonomy archives don't use `archive-`. They use `taxonomy-`.

Comment: perfect thanks @JacobPeattie